# Shiny numericInputs sums not updating as expected

Tags: r, shiny

I want to populate Shiny `numericInput` boxes with initial values from a named list. (The values and names are imported, but here just coded.) The initial values are summed and appear to the right of the numeric inputs.

I want the sum to update if I change the values in either `numericInput`. (I may not need to update either.) I can populate the values and get the initial sum. But, if I change a value, the sum does not update.

I tried an `observeEvent` to update the sum if I change a `numericInput`. The reactive "logic" I assumed in the MWE below is:

1. The initial values are reactive so that they can be updated.
2. `total` is a reactive value with the sum of the two reactive values.
3. The observeEvent watches for a change in `numericInput` (here just the first one) and updates the associated reactive value (`amounts$amt1`).
4. Because the reactive value is updated, I thought the `total` reactive would also update and thus update `output$total1`.

If I do not use the `observeEvent` for amt1, then the numeric inputs are properly initialized and summed, but subsequent changes to the inputs do not change the sum (total = 21). This makes sense because I don't have an `observeEvent` watching for changes.

If I include an `observeEvent`, then the observed `numericInput` resets to the default value (1) coded in the UI instead of using the initial value. The values are then summed. Subsequent changes to the inputs do not change the sum (total = 12).

**Question**

How do I populate the numeric inputs with initial values then update the sum if I change the initial values from the interface? I'm sure I'm not using the reactives correctly but I have not been able to figure out the correct way.

**MWE**

```
library(shiny)

vals <- as.list(c(10, 11))
names(vals) <- c("val1", "val2")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
      numericInput(
        inputId = "amt1", 
        label = "Amount 1",
        value = 1)
      ),
    column(3,
      numericInput(
        inputId = "amt2",
        label = "Amount 2",
        value = 2)
      ),
    column(3,
      textOutput("total1")
    )
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  amounts <- reactiveValues(
    amt1 = vals$val1,
    amt2 = vals[["val2"]]
  )

  observe({
    updateNumericInput(
      session,
      inputId = "amt1",
      value = amounts$amt1
    )
    updateNumericInput(
      session,
      inputId = "amt2",
      value = amounts$amt2
    )
  })

  total <- reactive({
    sum(amounts$amt1, amounts$amt2)
  })

  # If this runs, it resets input$amt1 to default value.
  observeEvent("input$amt1", {
    amounts$amt1 <- input$amt1
  })

  output$total1 <- renderText(total())

  # Tried this too, but it didn't change anything.
  #output$ui <- renderUI({
  #  tagList(
  #    numericInput("amt1", value = amounts$amt1),
  #    numericInput("amt2", value = amounts$amt2),
  #    output$total1 <- renderText(total())
  #  )
  #})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Here `observeEvent("amt1", {` you are observing a character vector. You need to write `observeEvent(input$amt1, {`

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Thanks, that was a mistake translating from the larger file to the MWE. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it way to complicated. Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)

vals <- as.list(c(10, 11))
names(vals) <- c("val1", "val2")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           numericInput(
             inputId = "amt1", 
             label = "Amount 1",
             value = vals[['val1']])
    ),
    column(3,
           numericInput(
             inputId = "amt2",
             label = "Amount 2",
             value = vals[['val2']])
    ),
    column(3,
           textOutput("total1")
    )
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  amounts = reactiveValues(
    amt1 = vals[['val1']],
    amt2 = vals[['val2']]
  )

  observe({
    amounts$amt1 = input$amt1
    amounts$amt2 = input$amt2
  })

  output$total1 = renderText({input$amt1 + input$amt2})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your example updates the sum based on the the changes to the input but it does not update the values in `vals`, which I also need. The `values = vals[['val1]]` initialization was helpful.

Comment: How are you using the updated `vals`? One way to update it is
`observe({
  vals <<- list(val1=input$amt1, val2=input$amt2)
})`

Comment: I use them on another panel. I also intend to save the values back to an rds file for future use. I did find a way to update vals, but your suggestion may be more concise. I tend to forget about `<<-`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are using them in another panel, it might be better to make a `reactiveValues` to contain them and update it in an observer.

Comment: That what I was trying to accomplish in the MWE. I stripped the code down to MWE so no panels but I have `reactiveValues` and an apparently not working observer.